# SDL ignoring my main file

Tags: c++, c, mingw, sdl, eclipse-cdt

I am running Eclipse CDT 64bits with MinGW and SDL. I have already read that SDL 'cleverly' redefines main method, and that it is sometimes precise to add #undef main in order to use my own main cpp. I have already done it, but when I try to run my app, my main is complety ignored (I put some breakpoints in order to realise so).

My main method goes like this:

```
#include "SDL/SDL.h"
#include "SDL/SDL_image.h"

#undef main

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) == -1) {
        printf("Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        return 1;
    }

        SDL_WM_SetCaption( "MarioKong", NULL );
```

I defined MinGW C++ Linker libraries on my project properties as follows: mingw32, SDLMain, SDL, SDL_image. I followed SDL installation notes as stated on ([lazyfoo](http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson01/windows/eclipse/index.php))

How can I run MY main file?

Comment: Please don't describe your problems as urgent. Everyone's question is urgent to them, and believe me it will hurt you more than it helps you (many people find it irritating).

Comment: **@Tim**: OK, thank you very much for the advice. I'll take that in mind.
**@Joachim**: Thanks, but I can't say I understand you : ) .

Comment: I believe he said: Don't link with SDLMain.

Comment: Oh, I hadn't caught the irony. Well, I had already tried that, but it did not work. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Why is there an `#undef main` in there?

Comment: Remove your `undef` and make sure you have `-mwindows` in your compiler flags.

Answer (score 1):

the clever way of redefining main is that you have the same main function on all platforms, and that you can use it the same everywhere. So no  #ifdef win32 WinMain else main etc. And you can use command line arguments equally on all platforms. So my advice is to just stick with  "int main(int argc, char* argv[])" and don't use the #undef main command